# Make google maps plugin black/white or with sepia filter

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-styling

I'm wondering if it is possible to display Google Maps in black/white or with a sepia filter. Can it be done with some Canvas magic? Or overlaying? Or some other method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Check this fiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/R5PXH/995/), I've desaturated all elements to create the black and white effect, for example:

```
{
   "featureType": "road.highway",
   "elementType": "geometry",
   "stylers": [
     { "saturation": -100 },
     { "lightness": -8 },
     { "gamma": 1.18 }
   ]
 }
```

[You can style your maps using this wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

or using [Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/editor) which is very user-friendly.

Answer (score 27):

Yes you can use styled maps feature of google api.

Here is an example
[http://www.programmableweb.com/news/make-your-google-map-stand-out-styles/2010/05/20](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/05/20/make-your-google-map-stand-out-with-styles/)

Here are the docs
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps

and here is a WYSIWYG wizard to recolor your map
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/imagefx/ brings a sepia and a desaturate (black and white) filter...
But it wont work in Safari and IE can only desaturate, no sepia

Answer (score 1):

I have this link in my history.  Someone has done it in flash http://www.anttikupila.com/GoogleMapsBw/[1](http://www.anttikupila.com/GoogleMapsBw/)

EDIT:
After considering your idea, I also found this [example](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html) I like it and you may be able to attach a listener to alter the images as they are loaded. but it may not work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks, but its flash. I wanted to make it with JS / HTML5. Will try the your tip with JS on the weekend